# Asynchronous signals from children to parent and sigaction()

Tags: c, unix, signals, posix

**Important pre-knowledge:** I have two children that were forked by the original process. The children simply send one of the two user-defined signals (SIGUSR1 or SIGUSR2) to the parent.

The code is constructed as follows:

```
if (pid == 0 || second_child == 0) {
    /* Just some pseudocode for basic logic */
    while (1) {
        sleep(2);
        kill(parent_pid, SIGUSR1) or kill(parent_pid, SIGUSR2);
    }
} else {
    while (1) {
        struct sigaction psa;
        psa.sa_handler = sigHandler;
        /* three signals that need to be handled */
        sigaction(SIGUSR1, &psa, NULL);
        sigaction(SIGUSR2, &psa, NULL);
        sigaction(SIGINT, &psa, NULL);
        pause();
    }
}
```

sigHandler method:

```
void sigHandler (int sigNum) {
    switch(sigNum) {
        case SIGUSR1:
            //print something using write()
            break;
        case SIGUSR2:
            //print something using write()
            break;
        default:
            exit(0);
    }
}
```

The calls to sigHandler() do not occur as they should. The print statements that occur in sigHandler() eventually just stop and there is no output. I believe the problem deals with a signal being sent to the parent while the sigHandler is being executed, but I am not certain.

Comment: If `// print something` involves `printf`, you have a problem.  `printf` is not safe to call from inside a signal handler.  Try using `write` instead.

Comment: I am using write(). I suppose I should specify that. Thanks anyways!

Comment: You are not clearing/setting `psa.sa_flags` or `psa.sa_mask`.  These need to be initialized.